# no respond_to block in edit action (generated with scaffold)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does anyone know why there is no `respond_to` block for generated `edit` actions? Every other action in typical scaffold controllers has a `respond_to` block in order to output `html` and `xml` formats. Why is the `edit` action an exception?

I'm using the latest version of Ruby on Rails (2.1.1).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rails handles the 99% case: It's fairly unlikely you'd ever need to do any XML or JSON translations in your Edit action, because non-visually, the Edit action is pretty much just like the Show action. Nonvisual clients that want to update a model in your application can call the controller this way

```
GET /my_models/[:id].xml (Show)
```

Then, the client app can make any transformations or edits and post (or put) the results to

```
PUT /my_models/[:id].xml (Update)
```

When you call this, you usually are doing it to get an editable form of the Show action:

```
GET /my_models/[:id]/edit
```

And it is intended for human use. 99% of the time, that is. Since it's unusual to transform the data in the Edit action, Rails assumes you aren't going to, and DRYs up your code by leaving respond_to out of the scaffold.

Comment: I understand that. However, there is a respond_to block for new actions. Wouldn't the same argument apply to the new actions as well?

Comment: The "new" action gives you an object with default fields filled in. You'll use them when you subsequently post to the "create" action, whether from a nonvisual client or an HTML screen.

Comment: And......as Ryan points out in his answer: The New action returns an XML template that you can use to fill in your model from a nonvisual client. Good call, Ryan.

Comment: @Pete Is to to add additional actions such as `render` that we use `format.html`? In other words, is it the usual case that respond_to is not used?

Answer (score 2):

Somewhat related.  Some may wonder why the rails scaffolding for the new action still has a respond_to block; whereas the edit action does not.  This is because a request to something like:

```
GET /my_models/new.xml
```

...gives back an XML template that can be used to create a new model.

Answer (score 1):

Because the edit action will only be called from HTML
There is no need for the edit form to be returned in an XML context.
Using REST, you simply make a put call directly to update with the relevant information.